# How to use the Split Command in Python?

Tags: python

I am making a text adventure game.
I am confused as to how to implement the next part of my game.
Here is what I have to add next:
" Add the ability to pick up an object. If the user types get key then:

1. Split the user input so you split out and just have a variable equal to “key”.

   1.Use the split method that's built into Python strings. For example:
   command_words = user_command.split(" ")

   This will split what the user types into a list. Each item separated out based on spaces.

   2. Update your directions to check command_words[0] instead.
   3. Add a check for a get command.

2.Search the list until you find an object that matches what the user is trying pick up.

This is the code I have so far:

```
done = False
object_list = []
room_list = []

class Object():
    def __init__(self, name, description, room):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.current_room = room

wand = Object("Holly Wand", "This wand is an 11\" supple wand made of holly and a single phoenix tail feather core.", 1)

object_list.append(wand)

dh_cloak = Object("Cloak of Invisibility", "This is part one part of the most powerful trifecta.  \nThis cloak shields you from all wandering eyes. \nFind all three parts and you may just be able to escape from this castle.", 3)

object_list.append(dh_cloak)

class Room():
    def __init__(self, describe, nw, n, ne, e, se, s, sw, w):
        self.description = describe
        self.northwest = nw
        self.north = n
        self.northeast = ne
        self.east = e
        self.southeast = se
        self.south = s
        self.southwest = sw
        self.west = w

kitchen = Room("You are in the Kitchen. Look at the scrumptious roast chicken and kidney pudding! \nThere are doors leading to North, East, and West.", None, 4, None, 2, None, None, None, 0)

room_list.append(kitchen)

east_cooridor = Room("You apparated into the East Corridor. \nYou can apparate to the Northwest or the Southwest.", 8, None, None, None, None, None, 2, None)

room_list.append(east_cooridor)

great_hall = Room("You are in the Great Hall. What is that great smell? \nThere appears to be doors leading to the north and the south.", None, 7, None, None, None, 1, None, None)

room_list.append(great_hall)

owlery = Room("You are in the Owlery. WHOOs got mail? There is a glass door overlooking the Forbidden Forest. \nThere are doors in every direction.", None, 9, None, 8, None, 4, None, 6)

room_list.append(owlery)

room_list.append(forbidden_forest)

current_room = 4
while not done:
    print(room_list[current_room].description)

key = current_room
i = 0
while i < len(object_list) and object_list[i].current_room != key:
    i += 1

if i < len(object_list):
    print("There is an object you can pick up in this room.")
    print()

direction = input("Which direction would you like to travel? ")
print()

if direction.lower() == "n" and current_room == 9 or direction.lower() == "north" and current_room == 9:
    print("You wandered too far into the Forbidden Forest with out all of the Deathly Hallows to protect you. \nYou have died.")
    done = True

elif direction.lower() == "nw" or direction.lower() == "northwest":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].northwest
    if next_room == None:
        print("TROLL! Troll in the dungeon!!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "n" or direction.lower() == "north":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].north
    if next_room == None:
        print("Run away!!!!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "ne" or direction.lower() == "northeast":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].northeast
    if next_room == None:
        print("Oh cool! Pixies! Wait...yikes! Bad idea!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()    

elif direction.lower() == "e" or direction.lower() == "east":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].east
    if next_room == None:
        print("Don't go over there! The Whomping Willow is over there!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "se" or direction.lower() == "southeast":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].southeast
    if next_room == None:
        print("Don't go in there...")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "s" or direction.lower() == "south":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].south
    if next_room == None:
        print("AHHH! It's Fluffy, the three-headed dog!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "sw" or direction.lower() == "southwest":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].southwest
    if next_room == None:
        print("The third floor corridor is forbidden.")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "w" or direction.lower() == "west":
    next_room = room_list[current_room].west
    if next_room == None:
        print("I wouldn't go that way if I were you. You may run into something dangerous!")
    else:
        current_room = next_room
    print()

elif direction.lower() == "q" or direction.lower() == quit:
    done = True

else:
    print("What kind of sorcery is this!? Try going an actual direction.")
    print()
```

I have tried to follow the directions given to me, but we were not taught about the split command and I can't find anything that explains it well online.
I was hoping that someone maybe able to explain to me how I use the split command to 'split' what the user types into a list.  I don't quite understand how or why I would do this.
Any advice on where to go from here would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: If you post a concise question, you are more likely to get help. You could easily remove a number of spells or rooms and it will make it a lot  easier understand your code.

Comment: Adding the concise portion of code that is causing problems would also help.

Comment: Refine your question please.

Comment: It seems that you have not yet attempted to write any code that implements the next part of the game. It would be better if you have a go at that first and then ask for help if it doesn't work. You already have instructions which give you some clues about how to do this. Which part are you confused about?

Comment: I revised my questions a little bit.  I have tried to follow the directions, but the wording and terms are very confusing to me. I am confused on how I would use a split command and what it does for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `split` method is often used in parsing users' commands that contain words separated by spaces or punctuation. For example...

```
brief_directions = ['n', 's', 'e', 'w', 'ne', 'nw', 'se', 'sw']
full_directions = ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west', 'northeast',
                   'northwest', 'southeast', 'southwest']
user_command = input('What would you like to do? ')
if user_command in brief_directions + full_directions:
    print('You want to go {}'.format(user_command))
else:
    command_words = user_command.split()
    print('You want to {verb} the {noun}'.format(verb=command_words[0], 
                                                 noun=command_words[1]))
```

> What would you like to do? get key
>
> You want to get the key

You could then write a single function which is called every time the user enters "get" as the first word, e.g.

```
if command_words[0] == "get":
    get_object(command_words[1])
```

That saves you from writing a separate bit of code for every object the user might conceivably want to get.

Comment: Thank you! This definitely helps.  Sorry for all of the confusion earlier!

Answer (score 0):

In an effort to explain `split` to you, here I go...

In Python, the `split` function is used as a string manipulator that allows the programmer, or user, to define a delimiter for which a string is to be chopped up, split. When the function is executed on a string, the string is transformed into a list of subsequent strings from the original that were separated and indexed at each occurrence of the defined delimiter.

For instance, say we have a string `"The cow jumped over the moon."` and we want to chop up the string where there are spaces. In order to do this, we use the `split` function.

```
s = "The cow jumped over the moon"
print(s.split(' '))
```

In this segment, I defined the delimiter as a `space`. The result of the code segment will print: `['The', 'cow', 'jumped', 'over', 'the', 'moon']`. As you can see, it returned a list of all substrings from the original, split where there was a space.

This principle applies for all arguments given to the `split` function as well. If we decided to split at ever occurrence of the letter `e`, we do:

```
s.split('e')
```

This will return: `['Th', ' cow jump', 'd ov', 'r th', ' moon']`

I hope this helps!